# select query get data from main table and all values in child table?

Tags: mysql, select

My tables structure is :

```
   Student:
     ID   Name         From
     1    student A    England
     2    student B    China
     3    student C    USA

   Subject:
     ID   id_student    Subject
     1     1            Maths
     2     1            Physics
     3     2            English
     4     3            Physics
     5     4            History
```

I want to get all data in main table (A) and all rows in have id_A in child table (B) to show in grid table like this :

```
ID    Student          Subject
1     student_A        Maths, Physics
2     student_B        English
3     student_C        Physics, History
```

I wonder how to select data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.Subject)
FROM Student AS t1
LEFT JOIN Subject AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.id_student
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Name
```

Comment: Wow...many thanks Giorgos Betsos!
By the way, how to break line each subject in result string ? Because i show in table, if this is long string (like : Maths <br/> Physics)